# appending javascript json/object to daynamoDB existing list "L" through apigClient and Lambda

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

Lambda function to append existing list:

```
    var doc = require('aws-sdk');
    var dynamo = new doc.DynamoDB({
        convertEmptyValues: true
    });

    exports.handler = function(event, context) {
        var params = {
            TableName: 'F_Items',
            Key: { // The primary key of the item (a map of attribute name to AttributeValue)

                "APIuserID": {
                    "N": event.APIuserID
                },
                "f_name": {
                    "S": event.f_name
                },
            },

            UpdateExpression: "SET #bks.#nm = list_append(#bks.#bl, :vals)",
            ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                "#bks": "Books",
                "#bl": "booklist",
            },
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ":vals": event.bVal,
            },
            ReturnValues: 'UPDATED_NEW',
            ReturnConsumedCapacity: 'NONE',
            ReturnItemCollectionMetrics: 'NONE',
        };

        dynamo.updateItem(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
            else context.succeed(data); // successful response
        });

    }
```

passing below values from javascript frontend Through API Getaway;

```
    var JSitem = {
        "aVal": "a",
        "bVal": "b",
        "nVal": 12
    };
    var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient();
    var body = {
        "APIuserID": "1",
        "f_name": "abc",
        "bVal": JSitem
    }
    apigClient.addingbookitemsPut({}, body, {})
        .then(function(result) {
            console.log("passed");
        }).catch(function(result) {
            console.log("err");
        });
```

issue here JSitem has to be "L" to be able to append it to list, how can I structure it so  **apigClient**  pass it as "L"

below structure doesn't help me

```
    var JSitem = [];

    JSitem["aVal"] = "a";
    JSitem["bVal"] = "b";
    JSitem["nVal"] = 12;
```

or

```
    var JSitem = [{
            aVal: 'a',
            bVal: 'b',
            nVal: 12
        }];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `document client` rather than dynamodb object. There seems to be an issue on `list_append` when you use dynamodb object.

The below code has the necessary changes that you require in your code.

```
 var doc = require('aws-sdk');
    var dynamo = new doc.DynamoDB({
        convertEmptyValues: true
    });

var docClient = new doc.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = function(event, context) {

    var params = {
    TableName: 'F_Items',
    Key: {

        "APIuserID":  event.APIuserID,
        "f_name": event.f_name,
    },

    UpdateExpression: "SET #bks.#nm = list_append(#bks.#bl, :vals)",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {            
        "#bks": "Books",
        "#bl": "booklist",
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":vals": event.bVal,
    },
    ReturnValues: 'UPDATED_NEW',
    ReturnConsumedCapacity: 'NONE',
    ReturnItemCollectionMetrics: 'NONE',
};

    docClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else context.succeed(data); // successful response
    });

}
```

**Request:-**

```
{
    "APIuserID" : 3,
    "f_name" : "name",
    "bVal" : ["somevalue"]
}
```

Comment: I have to use API getaway and lambda function

Comment: In lambda, you can use document client. It is part of aws sdk that you are already using in your code. Just check my require... didnt add anything new.

Comment: tried and got this module error
  "errorMessage": "AWS is not defined",
  "errorType": "ReferenceError".....

Comment: In your original code, you have defined  var doc = require('aws-sdk');.. In my code, I have defined like this var AWS = require("aws-sdk"); ... This is just a declaration issue.. Just ensure that var doc = require("aws-sdk"); .. var docClient = new doc.DynamoDB.DocumentClient(); ..

Comment: thats right, I am testing next step now, I am curious about performance comparison

Comment: It should not create any performance issue or performance should be same as dynamodb object. This API is a native library and available with in AWS SDK (i.e. not using any external libs). Please ensure that you are using docClient.update ... In the OP, it is dynamo.updateItem ..

Comment: I copied your code, still erros, this time I think it is related to     exports.handler = function(event, context), because it is missing there

Comment: I have updated the answer. You can just copy and paste now and try how it goes.

Comment: I am testing it on a fairly simple function; your approach doesn't even work there. while my function above work well.